# Array values reset in loop

Tags: c

So I am using `poll()` to read a couple gpio pins. I then compare previously read values to the newly read ones to see if they have changed. The reading of the values works just fine. My problem seems to be in the loop. This can be seen from the output where it looks like `buffers` is reset at the beginning of the loop. Why is this happening?

**Note:** In case anyone is wondering why I don't just use `poll()` as an interrupt with a delay of `-1`, it is because of a hardware issue that makes it unsupported.

### Code

```
static const int num_buttons = 2;

void *routine(){

    struct pollfd pfd[num_buttons];
    int fds[num_buttons];
    const char gpioValLocations[num_buttons][256];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_buttons ; i++){
        sprintf(gpioValLocations[i], "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", gpios[i]);
    }
    char buffers[num_buttons][2];
    char prev_buffers[num_buttons][2];

    for (i = 0; i < num_buttons; i++){
        if ((fds[i]= open(gpioValLocations[i],O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
            LOGD("failed on 1st open");
            exit(1);
        }
        pfd[i].fd = fds[i];  
        pfd[i].events = POLLIN;
        lseek(fds[i], 0, SEEK_SET); 
        read(fds[i], buffers[i], sizeof buffers[i]);
    }

    for (;;) {

        LOGD("at top: prev:%d%d buff:%d%d", atoi(prev_buffers[0]), atoi(prev_buffers[1]), atoi(buffers[0]), atoi(buffers[1]));

        poll(pfd, num_buttons, 1);

        for (i = 0; i < num_buttons; i++) {
            if ((pfd[i].revents & POLLIN)) {

                /* copy current values to compare to next to detected change */
                strcpy(prev_buffers[i], buffers[i]);
                LOGD("in loop: prev:%d%d buff:%d%d",
                 atoi(prev_buffers[0]), atoi(prev_buffers[1]),
                 atoi(buffers[0]), atoi(buffers[1]));

                /* read new values */
               lseek(fds[i], 0, SEEK_SET);
               read(fds[i], buffers[i], sizeof buffers[i]);

                /* compare new to previous */
                if (atoi(prev_buffers[i]) != atoi(buffers[i])) {
//                  LOGD("change detected");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
at top: prev:00 buff:01
in loop: prev:01 buff:00
in loop: prev:00 buff:00
at top: prev:00 buff:01
in loop: prev:01 buff:00
in loop: prev:00 buff:00
```

Comment: what is `strcopy`?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm

Comment: Ditto^ . Use `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks guys, `memcpy` solves the problem. Why doesn't `strcpy` work?

Comment: Because your incoming data isn't nulchar-terminated string data, a requirement of [`strcpy()` if you review the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy).. And please, next time post the *real* code. Obviously `read(fds[i], buffers[i], sizeof buffers[i];` doesn't compile either. (or does your compiler somehow synthesize closing parens from ether?).

Comment: It works with *null-terminated strings* only.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks. and yeah it is the real code, I just removed a `if  =  -1`  check to make everything more readable. If you want to put your comment in an answer I will accept

Comment: plz chill on the downvoting, I get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems risky:

```
strcpy(prev_buffers[i], buffers[i]);
```

`prev_buffers[i]` is only 2 bytes long.  If `buffers[i]` has more than 1 character, you have a buffer overflow and invoke undefined behavior.

Furthermore, you must initialize `buffers`, they currently start with random junk, not single byte character strings: using `strcpy` to save the *previous* values invokes undefined behavior.  Using `memcpy()` to save whatever previous contents is less risky as it will copy just 2 bytes, instead of scanning the buffers for a null terminator, potentially invoking undefined behavior both when reading past the end of `buffers[i]` and when writing past the end of `prev_buffers[i]`.

Are you sure that `read(fds[i], buffers[i], sizeof buffers[i]);` reads an ASCII digit and a null terminator?  If not, the code is incorrect.

Post a complete function that compiles, there might be more problems.

Comment: I know for sure they will only be 1 char long. That line is def the problem though

Comment: It didn;t read a null terminator, this was the problem. Update the answer and I will be happy to accept. I don;t think the missing bracket is a huge deal btw. Also a dummy read is performed before the loop which initializes buffers. I tried to post the minimal amount of code possible, perhaps I should have included more.

Comment: @StephanGM: It is preferable to post a complete compilable example that exhibits the problem.  Bugs tend to hide in innocent looking code.

Comment: I've added the rest